# enabling nullable feature has no effect

Tags: c#, .net

While I was upgrading a project recently, I found this issue, and could'nt figure out what was up, so I reproduced it with a very simple console template starter app in visual studio 2022.

So, let's say I created the application from a console app template, and it is set to dotnet 3.1 core.
It has this main method:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person = new personModel();
        person.name = "Test";
        Console.WriteLine(person.name);
    }
}
```

and this model, in another file:

```
internal class personModel
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

So, I now update the project to .NET 6, this should enable Null-state analysis and variable annotations, and I now expect to receive warnings on the two strings that I have declared.

But, If I change the csproj file to the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The appplication will still build with 0 warnings. I'm not getting any sguiggly lines either.
Ok, so I enable it manually:`<nullable>enable</nullable>`
But I still build and run with absolutely no warnings anywhere.
Why could this feature have no effect?

**EDIT**

It seems I was a bit too unclear with what I did.
The last thing I tried was adding `<nullable>enable</nullable>`
such that the `csproj` file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
      <nullable>enable</nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You said you added `<nullable>enable</nullable>` to the csproj, but the example you gave just below contains `<nullable>disable</nullable>`. Are you sure you used `enable` not `disable`?

Comment: ah sry, yes. It's just because I was playing a bit around with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is: the codebase should already have been using C# 8 or later version – because nullable reference types was not supported on previous versions of C#.

To check it, right-click in the project, go to properties and check the language version. I guess that your current language version starts as 7.3 or something else.

Comment: The language version was selcted by the .NET version, which was 3.1

Comment: Yes sure, but you can try to upgrade the language version in that case. Just go to the properties and try to update to C# 8.0 if .NET Version allow, then the nullability will works, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts):

> By default, nullable annotation and warning contexts are **disabled**. That means that your existing code compiles without changes and without generating any new warnings. Beginning with .NET 6, new projects include the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` element in all project templates.

So the sole update to .NET 6 and corresponding language version will not help, you need opt-in for example by adding to the .csproj:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: yes correct, but this I already tried

Answer (score 0):

Add `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` inside

```
<PropertyGroup><PropertyGroup>
```

in your .csproj file

Like :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: As described in the question, this had already been tried

Comment: @penstiaGarse can you please try **dotnet build** ? is it same as visual studio build result ? maybe there is something wrong with your ide